# How to use a Media queries in html css layout

Tags: php, html, css

Please tell me how to use media queries for iPhone. I can not understand how to write media queries for two devices like 321 to 479 and also other devices.

Please tell me how I can change responsive media queries in other devices.

Comment: How to use media Queries for iphone

Comment: How to ask a good question on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: also, this has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that , no matter which phone you are testing

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
  Here you can define all the responsive styles for mobile view. You can 
  resize the screen to the smallest screen resolution i.e iphone 4 320 * 
  480. So according to whatever the size is required, you can just define 
  it once. It will be applicable to all the devices.
}
```

Comment: you haven't explained min-width and max-width, nor corrected the OP's assumption that he is targeting devices, not screen widths.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow i agree with you he is targeting a particular width, but in the next line he also asking for other devices as well, so rather then giving him a particular width solution ```@media(max-width:767px)``` is better, which covers all the small devices.

Answer (score 0):

use: @media all and (max-width:200px){

}

What you put inside this will applay when the width will be less than the max-width you specify.
So on a laptop for example if somone resizes the browser less then 200 px the style inside will applay , and if a phone screen has the width less than your specified max-width the style will apply automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Media queries don't target specific devices (e.g. iPhone), they target screen widths (e.g. `min-width: 767px` and `max-width: 1024px`) and categories of devices and displays (print, screen).

There's a handy tutorial here:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 321px) {
    div.page {
       padding: 0.5em;
     }
}
```

Comment: It's not about only Iphone. There are other phones too that need to be worked on. Giving a solution for particular resolution is not a solution.

Comment: I know that, that's why I prefaced my remarks with an explanation of the fact that we are targeting screen-widths, not devices